# Trying to use. Find in VBA, getting error saying the object doest support the property or moethod

Tags: excel, vba

Here's the problem function. I've written lots of functions similar to this without issue and I've no idea what the problem is this time.

```
Sub FindEquipCost()
    Dim equipment As Range
    Set equipment = Sheets("Sheet1").Find("EQUIPMENT", 
     LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=True)
    MsgBox (equipment)
End Sub
```

Comment: `Find()` is a method of the `Range` object. Not the `Sheet` object. Instead: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range.Find("EQUIPMENT", LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=True)`

Comment: Needed to add range, thanks

Comment: You may also be missing a line continuation character "_" if the 'set equipment' line goes over two lines.

Comment: Unless you are 100% sure your value to be found always exists, you may want to code for the possibility of your value not being found (which will yeild an error when you try to use your variable `equipment`. A one liner way to do this is `If Not equipment is Nothing Then MsgBox (equipment)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `Find()` is a method of the `Range` object, not of the `Worksheets` object.

This is a way to run your code without an error:

```
Sub FindEquipCost()

    Dim equipment As Range
    Set equipment = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("EQUIPMENT", _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=True)

    If Not equipment Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox equipment.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "MISSING"
    End If

End Sub
```

See the `.Cells` between `Sheets()` and `.Find`.